# Kubernetes on GKE how to write data on PVC with readonlymany mode

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

As I want to share my PVC with multiple pods I have created a PVC with Readonlymany mode on GKE. Now how to put the data on that disk which all the other pods can use. In the documentation it says that GKE only support Readwriteonce and Readonlymany. So how to put my read-only data on the disk which other pods can use

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to seed the disk with data another way - before you mount it inside your Pods.

- You could create a disk from a snapshot of another disk that you regularly update with the necessary data
- This could be on a VM, or via another Pod that does the work
- Read the docs on ReadOnlyMany - https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#using_compute_engine_persistent_disks_as_readonlymany

Understanding more about what problem you want to solve will be helpful. If you truly need to write from multiple sources, then using Filestore (NFS) may address that: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gke-filestore-dynamic-provisioning

Comment: Already went through https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#using_compute_engine_persistent_disks_as_readonlymany My use case is for ReadOnlyMany only. Asume there is a webserver in the pods. And it reads web content from shared mount on DocRoot. But how to update the static mount in the PVC. I would need to update it often and dont want to restart pod whenever there is an update in image or css.  Initially thought to have a K8s Job which will write to PVC and all the webservers will read from the PVC but was not able to figure out how to achive the same

Comment: It sounds like a PV is not the fit here: why not use Google Cloud Storage (object storage) and access it from each pod?

Comment: How ? Dont want to use gcsfuse and I have already faced issue with it. Also this is just one of the use case. Another use case is there are some configuration files which are same for all the pods and managed externally. My application dynamically loads where there is a change in config. So in this scenario when ever I change the file I want to dump it to the shared location from where all pods can read.

Comment: You should put this context in your question - it’s hard to scope down your problem otherwise. You can’t directly solve this with a PV, so you should consider using a ConfigMap mounted as a volume in those Pods: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap - you can then update the ConfigMap and the files represented within will update in all associated Pods.